# Signing application in cmd with jarsigner

Tags: android, cmd, publishing, signed, jarsigner

I've been following this tutorial on [How to sign your app before publishing](http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-market-reviews/1317-tutorial-signing-your-apk-publishing.html) and everything works fine until the last step, number 6. When I enter my pass, i get this error

`jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: c:\Users\Vladimir\De
sktop\keytools\key\TermalneSonde1.keystore (The system cannot find the path spec
ified)`

I don't know what is the problem, but maybe it is connected to this: when I exported my project as unsigned pacakge, I got the next warning from eclipse:

```
An unsigned application was saved at ..., 
Before publishing the application you will need to:
-Sign the application with your release key,
-run zipalign on the signed package. Zipalign is located in <SDK> /tools/
```

So does anyone know what to do?

Comment: why don't you just try exporting the apk via Eclipse : File > Export > Android > Export Android Application. You have options to sign the apk    there

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to get AIDE on the Play Store and get the AIDE Premium Key. You move your project folder to a path on your SD Card for your android device called AppProjects. Now there is a few steps that you must do from there.
-Move your publishing key to any path of the SD Card just remember where you put ut
-Click the Menu Key on your device (Or however you open an options menu)
-Find the option called "Export APK"
-Type in the path on your SD that you want the application's APK to be stored.
-Type in the path that your publishing Key is If it is correct, a button will appear that says "Export." The APK will be built, just wait, and then you can publish from your device (Do not use Opera Browsers to upload your APK to Google Play) or you can move the APK to your computer/laptop and publish there

Comment: This advice means "Buy the AIDE Premium Key and you will be able to do this" :-) Are there any free options?